# ref.current.scrollLeft returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, ref, react-ref

I have piece of code:

```
`function App() {
  const myRef = useRef(null);

  const onWheel = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const containerScrollPosition = myRef.current.scrollLeft;

    inputEl.current.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: containerScrollPosition + e.deltaY * 0.35,
      behaviour: "smooth"
    });
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{
        height: 440,
        width: "100%"
      }}
      onWheel={onWheel}
    >
      <AutoSizer>
        {({ height, width }) => (
          <List
            ref={myRef}
            height={height}
            itemCount={30}
            itemSize={600}
            layout="horizontal"
            width={width}
          >
            {Grid}
          </List>
        )}
      </AutoSizer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When i use `myRef` for `List` component, `myRef.current.scrollLeft`/`myRef.current.clientHeight` returns `undefined`(`myRef.current` returns correct component node). If i use `myRef` for `div.App` all goes right. 
What could be the problem?

Comment: Please give more information for AutoSizer, List and Grid.

Comment: @Puckwang, List and Autosize - https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window#can-a-list-or-a-grid-fill-100-the-width-or-height-of-a-page. Grid is my custom ag-grid grid.

Answer (score 0):

The List ref is not a dom node and does not have scrollLeft property. You could use the scrollOffset of the list which is stored in it's state.

```
  const handleScrollLeft = () => {
      let scrollPosition = listRef.state.scrollOffset - 50 
      listRef.scrollTo(scrollPosition)
  }
```